# Filter by category when starting agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I'm using the following config for my most used agenda view:

```
    ("c" "Daily plan"
     ((agenda ""((org-agenda-ndays 1)
         (org-agenda-category-filter '("+life"))
         (org-agenda-sorting-strategy
          (quote ((agenda time-up priority-down tag-up))))
         (org-deadline-warning-days 14)))
     (todo "TODO")
     (todo "NEXT"
    ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'scheduled 'deadline))))
     (todo "WAIT"))
    ((org-agenda-tag-filter-preset '("-chores"))))
```

Additionally I have only two main org-mode files: life and work, what I'd like to do is to set my emacs so that when I start it at work agenda shows  entries filtered by default to work only (same as navigating to a work entry in agenda and pressing '<'). It's not much typing but being unable to automate this irritates me a lot.

As you can see in line 3 I've tried to specify that life is always the default filter but it did not work. Any ideas of how this can be done?

Comment: Please fix the indentation and unbalanced parens in your code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `org-agenda-category-filter` doesn't actually set a filter.  It seems to just be part of `org-agenda-filter-by-categories` internal workings.  The variable you want is `org-agenda-category-filter-preset` which should be a list of strings like "+life".  This setting is global to the entire agenda so it *must* be set in the global options of the agenda command (where you have `org-agenda-tag-filter-preset` now).

Comment: It worked! Thanks, I've somehow missed this.

Comment: the problem now is that pressing '<' switches between '<+life>' and '<+life+life>' filter so I cannot go back to main view. Any idea how to approach this?

Comment: That is strange.  It looks to me like a bug in the category filtering.  Try asking on the mailing list